# Why does the clang 6.0 compiler optimize by starting indexes at -N and counting to zero, but clang 11.0 starts at 0 and counts to N?

Tags: c

For the code below, clang 6.0 and 11.0 have a subtle difference in their compiled assembly.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZE (1L << 16)
    
void test(uint8_t * restrict a,  uint8_t * restrict b) {
  uint64_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    a[i] += b[i];
  } 
}
```

When I compile with arguments `-O1` in clang 6.0, I get the following output:

```
test:                                   # @test
        mov     rax, -65536
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rsi + rax + 65536]
        add     byte ptr [rdi + rax + 65536], cl
        add     rax, 1
        jne     .LBB0_1
        ret
```

Notice that the compiler changes the loop from a '0 to 65536' index to '-65536 to 0'. I thought this was very clever, because it makes use off the fact that `add` in assembly will set the `ZF` flag if the result is zero, saving an instruction. Unfortunately when I run the same code with the same arguments in clang 11.0, I get the following code:

```
test:                                   # @test
        xor     eax, eax
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rsi + rax]
        add     byte ptr [rdi + rax], cl
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rax, 65536
        jne     .LBB0_1
        ret
```

Notice this time, it keeps the '0 to 65536' index, and adds a `cmp` instruction at the end of each loop. Also, while this is a specific example, this is not unique to the code I wrote. It persists with `-O3` and vectorization enabled as well

What gives? Was the original optimization not actually effective? Did processors change to obviate the trick?

Comment: The clang 6 version may be fewer instructions, but are you sure it is actually better in terms of size or speed?  I haven't counted the bytes, but with the displacements that are now needed in the `movzx` and `add` instructions, the clang 6 version may in fact be larger.

Comment: `O1` is not a particularly meaningful optimization level

Comment: Another way would be to subtract 65536 from `rsi` and `rdi` before you start. Then you get the best of both worlds (assuming that it's the size of the loop code that you want to minimise). But it feels kind of hacky.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have no clue which is better in either dimension. I was just curious why they changed. I have a very small understanding of assembly; just enough to read what's going on. I just know the people who write clang compilers are smart, so there must have been a good reason for the trick in 6.0, but that's also why I'm confused about the trick disappearing.

Comment: @M.M I originally had -O3 and vectorization turned on, but it added so much clutter to the loop body and detracted from the question, so I switched to -O1 to be more readable. But the exact same phenomenon happens in -O3.

Comment: cant reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/oahMjq

Comment: @MatthewKolbe Sorry - but only 6 version does. I think that was an experimental optimization attempt, and it was abandoned in later versions.

Comment: @0___________ I think you're right. I hope someone who was working on the compiler will weigh in on how they came to try and abandon the trick.

Comment: @they rather focus on the most commonly used -O2 which is the most efficient as I see. https://godbolt.org/z/fKfThT

Comment: @MatthewKolbe or https://godbolt.org/z/Wvds9e

Comment: If you really want to know, there's always `git bisect`...